# Where does NLog's InstallNLogConfig.exe tool install to?

Tags: nlog

Using NLog, I would like to take advantage of the `<uninstall-command>` directives. On the documentation [HERE](http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/25/deploying-nlog-configuration.html), I see that you can do this:

```
> InstallNLogConfig.exe c:\path\to\NLog.config
```

But I don't have `InstallNLogConfig.exe` in my path and I can't find the file. I originally installed Nlog via Nuget, and then download the `NLog-v2.0.0.2000.msi` installer.

Where is this file located? Or, alternatively, how should it be used?

Comment: do you mean, where can I download it? Or how to add to my path?

Comment: I would like to add it to my path. But I don't know where it installed to. I was able to use it from within c# so it definitely exits

Comment: Ugh. Mobile keyboards. Exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NLog 2 there was a MSI package, but currently all software is distributed with NuGet. As it's a MSI package, you could install it where you want, so check the your installed programs.

A more recent version of InstallNLogConfig.exe is available as NuGet package: [NLog.InstallNLogConfig](https://www.NuGet.org/packages/NLog.InstallNLogConfig/).

Manual download it and extract it by renaming it to .zip or use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer):

[image]